# Angular: referencing EmbeddedViewRef from a component

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Quoting Angular core API docs page on [EmbeddedViewRef](https://angular.io/api/core/EmbeddedViewRef):

> An embedded view can be referenced from a component other than the hosting component whose template defines it, or it can be defined independently by a TemplateRef.

It's clear to me that for the latter I can create an `EmbeddedViewRef` instance from a `TemplateRef` instance, e.g.,

**example.component.html**

```html
<p>Hip!</p>
<ng-container #vc></ng-container>
<ng-template #tpl>
  <p>Hip!</p>
</ng-template>
<p>Hooray!</p>
```

**example.component.ts**

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
  const embeddedView = this.tpl.createEmbeddedView(null);
  this.vc.insert(embeddedView);
}
```

But it still leaves me an open question about the former: how do we reference an embedded view from a component other than the hosting component whose template defines it?

Comment: What do you mean by reference? When you add it to the view container that is a reference for the component that owns the view. So it will be destroyed when the component is destroyed.

Comment: @Reactgular I believe the term "reference" I used there is also part of my confusion (I was just repeating what the docs says). In my example component above, I know #vc is my reference to the view container, but: "An embedded view can be referenced from a component other than the hosting component whose template defines it" - what does it mean by: 1) "reference" 2) "a component other than the hosting component whose template defines it"??

Comment: I believe, but I need to verify before I post as an answer. That the `EmbeddedViewRef` references a different value for `this` such that it points to a different component. So when you call methods in `<ng-template>` that those methods continue to be called on the original component. I need to test this to make sure I'm right, but if I am it means that the embedded view is linked to the life cycle of two components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> An embedded view can be referenced from a component other than the hosting component whose template defines it, or it can be defined independently by a TemplateRef.

They are referring to the value of `this` in the template.

When you write an expression like `<h1>{{value}}</h1>` it is referencing the property named `value` on the current component. We don't prefix the expression with *this*, for example `<h1>{{this.value}}</h1>` as the *context* is always the component.

So when you create an embedded view from a template reference. The component that the template originates from persists to be the context for `this`. This is what they mean by "can be referenced from a component other than the hosting component". The fact that the view was attached to the view container of another component doesn't change the value of `this` in the template.

This is an import fact about embedded views that isn't clearly explained in the documentation. When you attach an embedded view to a view container of **another** component, then that embedded view follows the life cycle of that *other* component. Which means, if the original component that created the embedded view is *destroyed* then the embedded view continues to reference the value of `this` which is now a destroyed component.

You can get around this by *destroying* the embedded view when the component that creates it is also destroyed.

I've created a stackblitz that illustrates the issue. The "child" component creates an embedded view, and attaches it to the view container of a parent component. The embedded view references the child's properties and calls a method. This happens from the view of another component illustrating that the value of `this` does not change, but when the "child" is destroyed I must also destroy the embedded view.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eg4vpf

Now, go back to the stackblitz and comment out line 27 in the `child.component.ts` so that the view is not destroyed. See how template references continue to reference `this` after the app is cleared, but the components that created those templates have been destroyed. That would be a bug in the app then.